# Copy from a template in Google Sheet API with the most restrictive scope possible

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to use Google Sheet API to create a spreadsheet, write some values and then copy a sheet from another spreadsheet (public).

I know how to copy using SheetService.Spreadsheets.Sheets.CopyTo() and work just fine .the problem is that for this my app has to ask for:

```
"View your Google Spreadsheets"
(SCOPE: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly)
```

and is not true, my app dont want to see the user spreadsheets. Only want to 
see, edit spreadsheet made by the app. so i want to use this scope:

```
"View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app"
(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file)
```

Is posible to copy a sheet from a shared spreadsheet without asking for see **ALL** the user spreadsheets?

Comment: Hi @Krone, did you find a solution to this problem yet?

Comment: @jarora nop sorry man